# How to classify groups based on changes from the previous period in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis, window-functions

Good day to everyone!
I have a table with some teams and their rating for the period. Data looks like this:

| team | date | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| team_1 | 2022-09 | 7.5 |
| team_1 | 2022-12 | 8 |
| team_1 | 2023-03 | 8.5 |
| team_2 | 2022-09 | 8 |
| team_2 | 2022-12 | 7 |
| team_2 | 2023-03 | 8 |
| team_3 | 2022-09 | 8 |
| team_3 | 2022-12 | 8 |
| team_3 | 2023-03 | 7 |
| team_4 | 2022-09 | 9 |
| team_4 | 2022-12 | 8 |
| team_4 | 2023-03 | 7 |

As we can see, rating of the team may increase or decrease comparing to the last period, or it can change for two consecutive periods. Thus, team may be classified to one of following groups:

1. Increasing for two consecutive periods
2. Increased compared to the last period
3. Decreased compared to the last period
4. Decreasing for two consecutive periods

In this sample, the result should be like this:

| team | status |
| --- | --- |
| team_1 | Increasing for two consecutive periods |
| team_2 | Increased compared to the last period |
| team_3 | Decreased compared to the last period |
| team_4 | Decreasing for two consecutive periods |

My question is how can I get such result? I suspect there should be some window function, but I'm not sure how exactly to use it.

Comment: Do you ever have more than three periods worth of data for a team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, window functions, like here:

```
select team, case sgn when  1 then 'increasing ' 
                      when -1 then 'decreasing '
                      else 'stable '
             end ||'for '||cnt||' period(s)' status
from (
  select team, dt, sgn, rn, 
         count(1) over (partition by team, sgn order by dt) cnt
  from ( 
    select team, dt, rating, 
           sign(rating - lag(rating) over (partition by team order by dt)) sgn, 
           row_number() over (partition by team order by dt desc) rn 
      from teams ) t1 ) t2
where rn = 1
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/I8ak1uAC)

Compare ratings for each row using lag(), assign sign to get values -1, 0 or 1. Then count these consecutive values for each team and take last row, found with row_number(). Use `case ... when` to present values as you wanted.

---

Edit:

In the above query I assumed, that there can be maximum three enntries for each team, because these were possible team statuses. In case there are more entries gap-n-islands problem need to be solved at first, so query has to be modified like:

```
select team, case sgn when  1 then 'increasing ' 
                      when -1 then 'decreasing '
                      else 'stable '
             end ||'for '||cnt||' period(s)' status
from (
  select team, dt, sgn, rn, count(1) over (partition by team, grp, sgn order by dt) cnt
  from (
    select team, dt, sgn, rn, sum(grp) over (partition by team order by dt) grp
    from (
      select team, dt, sgn, rn,  
             case when sgn <> lag(sgn) over (partition by team order by dt) 
             then 1 else 0 end grp
      from ( 
        select team, dt, rating, 
               sign(rating - lag(rating) over (partition by team order by dt)) sgn, 
               row_number() over (partition by team order by dt desc) rn 
        from teams ) t1) t2 ) t3 ) t4 
  where rn = 1
```

so it counts only last consecutive series.

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MoBAEu44)

Comment: Per my understanding, I don't believe this logic handles the concept of "most recent and consecutive" See https://dbfiddle.uk/Pt5A8hHJ for instance. I guess I'm not sure if it's fair to assume there are never more than three rows per team.

Comment: @shawnt00 - But here number of entries is limited to three, so there can no be gaps and islands. If it was, I would group them when status changes and then count.

Comment: As there are ways to write this without that assumption I feel inclined to note it.

Comment: @shawnt00 - added this info and query for any number of rows.

Comment: Would it be easier to just say `case when sum(sgn) over (partition by team order by dt desc rows between 2 preceding and current row) = -2 ...`?

Comment: @shawnt00 Yes, but now we are talking about entries limited to three, not universal number. Now last query may show "decreasing for 6 periods". And yes, most of the solutons may be shortened, improved.

Comment: My point was that your initial query just needed to use a narrower window to determine whether last two were consecutive increase/decrease.

Comment: @shawnt00 - Yep, but `between 1 preceding and current row`: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PISU97Av).

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I ended answering a slightly more general case by not limiting comparisons to 3 periods.

It creates a difficult situation where having a rating e.g. increase, then pause (or decrease), then increase again requires us to ignore the first increase and only keep the last.

```sql
WITH T(Team, Date, Sign) AS (
    SELECT Team, Date, SIGN(Rating - LAG(Rating) OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY date))
    FROM MyTable
), LastChange(Team, Date) AS(
    SELECT Team, LEAST(COALESCE(MAX(Date) FILTER (WHERE Sign >= 0),''), COALESCE(MAX(Date) FILTER (WHERE Sign <= 0),''))
    FROM T
    GROUP BY Team
)
SELECT T1.Team,
       CASE T1.Sign WHEN 1 THEN 'Increasing' ELSE 'Decreasing' END AS Direction,
       COUNT(T2.*) AS ForLastConsecutive
FROM T T1
JOIN T T2 
    ON  T1.Team = T2.Team
    AND T1.Sign * T2.Sign > 0
JOIN LastChange ON T2.Team = LastChange.Team AND T2.Date >= LastChange.Date
WHERE T1.Date = '2023-03'
GROUP BY T1.Team, T1.Sign
ORDER BY Team
```

I let you combine the last 2 columns into a `status` column.

Explanation:

1. The sign of the difference of 2 consecutive ratings gives you the direction of the change. In the main query, when multiplying 2 signs from joined tables, we want to keep the `1 * 1` and the `-1 * -1`, both being `> 0`.
   This product simplifies the `JOIN` criteria quite a bit.
2. The second trick is theCTE `LastChange`, which will find the date of the last increase and of the last decrease and, out of both, will keep the earlier date.
   Note that if the rating of a team only keeps increasing, then the date returned by `COALESCE(MAX(Date) FILTER (WHERE Sign <= 0)` will be `NULL` (and symmetrically if it keeps decreasing). In order for the `LEAST()` to work well, we need a `COALESCE`.
   Because your column `date` is in fact a text (the day is missing), I used `''`. If it was an actual date, you would need to use `-infinity`.

You can try what difference it makes with the below sample, in which I added 1 value for `team_3`:

```sql
WITH MyTable(Team,date,rating) AS (
    VALUES
    ('team_1','2022-09',7.5),
    ('team_1','2022-12',8),
    ('team_1','2023-03',8.5),
    ('team_2','2022-09',8),
    ('team_2','2022-12',7),
    ('team_2','2023-03',8),
    ('team_3','2022-06',9),
    ('team_3','2022-09',8),
    ('team_3','2022-12',8),
    ('team_3','2023-03',7),
    ('team_4','2022-09',9),
    ('team_4','2022-12',8),
    ('team_4','2023-03',7)
), ...
```